# React and Antd TreeSelect - Sorting Table by TreeSelect Multi-Select Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have a table that I am trying to query with a Antd TreeSelect component.

[image]

The TreeSelect lists Category and Sub-Category selections which you can see under the item names (i.e. Speaker System is under Furniture > Chairs (sorry my test data doesn't make sense)).

When I click on tree nodes it calls this function via `onChange`.

```
  const onChange = (value, title) => {
    // highlight tree dropdown correctly
    setTreeSelections(value);

    // add selections to query string and update table per query string
    setTreeQueryItems(title);
    console.log(treeQueryItems);
    const matches = nsData.itemSort.filter((o) =>
      treeQueryItems.every((tag) => Object.values(o).includes(tag))
    );
    setInventoryDataFiltered(matches);
  };
```

setTreeSelection is a setState to work the highlighting and selected value in the TreeSelect component - that's all working fine.

setTreeQueryItems builds my array of selections to then run through the filter method to query my table and return only the ones that match my TreeSelect selections. That works well but it's always a state behind and I can't figure it out. Thinking it has something to do with setState being async but I need some guidance.

Here's an example of it being a state behind.

1. Click iPads, no change to the table object and my `console.log(treeQueryitems)` shows an empty array.

[image]

2. Click Tablets, my table object now updates to show just items matching "iPads" in any field and `console.log(treeQueryitems)` shows iPad in it.

[image]

If I were to select another then my table would update to show just iPads and Tablets and then on and on. It's always one selection behind.

Any thoughts?